# how to convert yyyy-dd-mmThh:mm:ss in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

```
+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
|          ip        |event_status|         timestamp|
+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
|          10.111.8.1|          OK|2017-05-18T13:31:38|
|         10.101.21.1|          OK|2017-05-18T23:45:01|
|        10.75.100.50|          OK|2017-05-21T02:30:02|
+------------------------------------------------------
```

I have above dataset , I need to convert format for timestamp to `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"`

so I can calculate timestamp I am trying to achieve below dataset

```
+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
|          ip        |event_status|         timestamp|
+--------------------+------------+-------------------+
|          10.111.8.1|          OK|2017-05-18 13:31:38|
|         10.101.21.1|          OK|2017-05-18 23:45:01|
|        10.75.100.50|          OK|2017-05-21 02:30:02|
+------------------------------------------------------
```

somehow java datatime format doesn't work

any idea how to convert this time format either in scala or spark sql

Answer (score 0):

just cast it:

```
val newDF = df.withColumn("timestamp", $"timestamp".cast("timestamp"))
```

Comment: Thanks but cast didn't workout for me I tried that option earlier so ask this question is there any scala function that I can use to convert this format

Comment: @MikeVZ what version of spark are you using? is it 1.X.X? a lot of time related tools were added in spark 2.X.X

Comment: I am using zeppelin notebook 0.7.1 version so scala interpreter comes with it but don't know whats the version of scala

Comment: @MikeVZ its the version of spark that counts. just do spark.version or sc.version

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a simple UDF to generate the timestamp-formatted string:

```
val ds = Seq(
  ("10.111.8.1", "OK", "2017-05-18T13:31:38"),
  ("10.101.21.1", "OK", "2017-05-18T23:45:01"),
  ("10.75.100.50", "OK", "2017-05-21T02:30:02")
).toDF(
  "ip", "event_status", "timestamp"
).as[(String, String, String)]

def convertTS = udf((s: String) => s.split("T").mkString(" "))

val ds2 = ds.withColumn("timestamp", convertTS($"timestamp"))

ds2.show
+------------+------------+-------------------+
|          ip|event_status|          timestamp|
+------------+------------+-------------------+
|  10.111.8.1|          OK|2017-05-18 13:31:38|
| 10.101.21.1|          OK|2017-05-18 23:45:01|
|10.75.100.50|          OK|2017-05-21 02:30:02|
+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Appreciate help

Comment: one question in convertTS function where mkString has defined

Comment: [mkString](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-convert-scala-collections-to-string-mkstring) is a standard Scala method for concatenating collection elements into a string.

Comment: On a separate note, this solution is recommended only if you want the exact format in string as indicated in your question.  In case you need to manipulate the column as actual timestamp, @Assaf Mendelson's type casting suggestion would be more suitable.  If casting directly from the original column doesn't work for your Spark version, try cast it after applying `convertTS` – i.e. `ds.withColumn("timestamp", convertTS($"timestamp").cast("timestamp"))`

Comment: understood , thanks everyone who responded ,appreciate it everyone's time and support , its time to buy scala book :-)